# Deploy multiple Application to the same Azure web app viaAzure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release

I've a two applications, backend and frontend, hosted on the same Azure web app `(os : windows)`.

Actually, i Deploy the two artficats via FTP/S.

I use `wwwroot folder` to the front and a subfolder in `wwwroot folder` to the backend

I would use Azure Devops to  create a Azure Release to deploy the two application to my web app.

I can't use two app service for the backend and the frontend.

What is the best approch to deploy ? and It's possible to specify a subfolder target in Azure App service into Azure release ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to specify a subfolder to deploy to in azure release pipeline using the [deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops)s. The artifacts will be deployed to wwwroot folder by default.

However,You can use [copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#arguments) in your release pipeline to copy the backend artifacts into the subfolder which resides in the frontend artifacts folder. And then deploy the frontend artifacts folder which contains the backend artifacts in its subfolder. See below:

[image]

You can also run [Kudu rest api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) in [azure powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) to deploy to azure web app service.

You can  first use the [command api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#command) to create a subfolder in wwwroot.

```
{
 "command" = 'md subfolder',
 "dir"='D:\home\site\wwwroot'
}
```

Then you can deploy the backend artifacts to the subfolder using [zip deploy api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip)

`$apiUrl = "https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/subfolder"`

Please check out [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-to-azure-platform-as-a-service-websites-using-kudu-rest-apis/) for more information. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139151/azure-app-service-deploy-task-option-to-remove-files-in-container-upon-deploymen/62147665#62147665) for example using azure powershell task to call kudu rest api

Comment: When deploy the front , the folder of backend will be deleted , is it ?

Comment: @Andrelemarchand I tested and found if the subfolder was created by kudu api. The subfolder will not be deleted when deploy the front to wwwroot.

Comment: When deploy with azure devops ?

Comment: @Andrelemarchand Yes

Comment: The wwwroot folder have the two artficats , if i Deploy the backend with kudu api to subfolder in wwwroot , this folder will not be deleted if i Deploy the frontend ?

Comment: @Andrelemarchand From the result of my test. Its behavior looks like this. (The `removeAdditionalFilesFlag`  of azure web app deploy task should be set to `false`)

Comment: @Andrelemarchand Did you get a chance to try out above solution. How did it go?